# Python tkinter geometry management thin white line between widgets

Tags: tkinter

When I use the tkinter grid geometry manager there is always a thin white line between widgets.
Is there any way to remove this line so that the widgets are flush with each other?

```py
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.w = Canvas(self.parent,width = 100,height = 100,\
            bg = 'green',bd = 0)
        self.w.grid(row = 0,column = 0)        
        self.w1 = Canvas(self.parent,width = 100,height = 100,\
            bg = 'blue',bd = 0)
        self.w1.grid(row = 0,column = 1)        
        self.w2 = Canvas(self.parent,width = 100,height = 100,\
            bg = 'red',bd = 0)
        self.w2.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
        self.w3 = Canvas(self.parent,width = 100,height = 100,\
            bg = 'yellow',bd = 0)
        self.w3.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
def main():
    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Without seeing your code I cant tell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

It is the *highlight* around the canvases which can be removed by setting `highlightthickness=0` in every `Canvas(...)`.